# How can I update the cursor and get real state?

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

There are 3 py files, Client, Server and SQL.

Client get computername and username, then send to Server through socket.

Server get data, call SQL to update MySQL, then reply 'OK'to client.

Now run server, run client, it will add data successfully.

Run client again,it will show 'It has been added' .

But I delete the data in MySQL and run client again(**Server is still on**), it should add data again **but not**. Still show  'It has been added'

- If I turn off server then call it again, the data can be added successfully.
- If I add new data, then delete it in MySQL, it also can be added successfully,
- Only when I add new data, then **run client again**, then delete data in MySQL, I can not add data again unless restart server.

==========  Server  ==========

```
'''

......

'''

def clientThread(conn):

    message = conn.recv(1024)

    data = message.split(' ')

    computer_name = data[0]

    user_name = data[1]

    main(computer_name,user_name) //call SQL

    reply = 'OK'

    conn.sendall(reply)  

    conn.close()   

while 1:  

conn,addr = s.accept() 

clientThread(conn)
```

==========  SQL  ==========

```
'''
......
'''


def searchComputerName(computer_name):

    c = db.cursor()

    sql="SELECT * FROM `mtk_pc_name` WHERE name='%s'"%computer_name

    if(c.execute(sql)):

        common_ID = c.fetchone()[0]

        c.close()
        return common_ID
    else:
        print'searchComputerName false'
    c.close()
    return False

def main(computer_name,user_name):

    common_ID=searchComputerName(computer_name)

    if(common_ID):
        if(compareUserName(common_ID,user_name)):
             print"It has been added."
        else:
             updateUserName(common_ID,user_name)
    else:
        common_ID=searchUserName(user_name)
        if(common_ID):
             updateComputerName(common_ID,computer_name)
        else:
             addNewItem(user_name,computer_name)
```

Comment: I expect you are seeing issues with transactions. But without seeing any code, there's no way to help further.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I`m sorry I can`t post whole code at once.Because of company policy, I had to  connect Internet through remote desktop and I can`t copy my code to the remote desktop. I hope this main code is enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

In each function in SQL add the following:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=hostName,user=userName,passwd=password,db=database)

cursor=db.cursor()
```

It`s working OK now.

Obviously I will extract it as parameter of function. At last ,it looks like this:

```
def searchComputerName(computer_name,cursor):
def addNewItem(user_name,computer_name,cursor,db):
```

Although I do not konw why global db and cursor declared at first do not work well.